# Rewrite url segment with .htaccess i.e. ca_en becomes en-ca

Tags: .htaccess

.htaccess == voodoo magic

I have googled but haven't found something that I can cut & paste to change an url segment to something else. Basically I need to change

domain.com/en/ to domain.com/en-us
domain.com/ca_en/ to domain.com/en-ca

for all urls. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you mean by "change", as there is externally redirecting to force the browser to make a new request for a different URL, or internally changing the URI to point to a different resource on the server and the browser (or any client) is completely unaware of this change.

For the first, e.g. externally redirecting:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/en/(.*)$ $1/en-us/$2
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)/ca_en/(.*)$ $1/en-ca/$2
```

For the second, e.g. internally rewriting the URI

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/en/(.*)$ /$1/en-us/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ca_en/(.*)$ /$1/en-ca/$2 [L]
```